# VGA output not detected with Linux Nvidia driver

Tags: linux, nvidia-graphics-card, vga

I'm having a problem with getting the VGA out to work on my laptop. I have a Sony Vaio F series running Fedora 13 64bit with an Nvidia 330M on driver 254.44. Quite simply, the VGA out is not detected although the HDMI out is. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I forgot that since I was using the "Connected-monitor" option in my xorg.conf that it needed to be changed from DFP-1 for my HDMI output to CRT for VGA. All is well now.